# Magento : Product detail page GIF image not call / working

Tags: magento-1.9, frontend, product-images

Here my code use in our local environment it's working but in live site not working When i click image gif image not open it live site.but in localhost it's working properly

```
$baseDir = Mage::getBaseDir('media');
  $file = ('gif' == strtolower(pathinfo($this->_baseFile, PATHINFO_EXTENSION))) ? $this->_baseFile : $this->_newFile;
  $path = str_replace($baseDir . DS, "", $file);
  return Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . str_replace(DS, '/', $path);
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting in live? Can you check if returns correct url.

Comment: i have the same problem. Don't get any error message but GIF image is not working on detail page. I have also used same code and it's working fine in localhost but not working in live site.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below changes in file :

copy file from

path : `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Image.php` to

path : `app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Image.php` (create folders if necessary)
Find the line public function getUrl() and replace the function with:

```
public function getUrl()
    {
        $baseDir = Mage::getBaseDir('media');
        $file = ('gif' == strtolower(pathinfo($this->_baseFile, PATHINFO_EXTENSION))) ? $this->_baseFile : $this->_newFile;
        $path = str_replace($baseDir . DS, "", $file);
        return Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . str_replace(DS, '/', $path);
    }
```

**hope this will help you.**

Comment: this is magneto1 i am using magneto2